# Trigger an action after user tweets through iOS6 "tweet sheet"

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios6

I'd like to trigger a specific action after a user tweets something through iOS6's built-in "tweet sheet"

[image: Tweet Sheet]

I want to trigger a method after the user hits its "Send" button.

Alternatively, if I can receive some confirmation from the iOS that a tweet was successfully posted, I'd like to trigger the method then.

Are either of these options possible? Is there a different, preferred way to trigger an action after a user posts a tweet?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Could you point me to a resource on accessing these controllers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the completion handler.  See code example below.

```
SLComposeViewController *tweetSheet = [SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter];
tweetSheet.completionHandler = ^(SLComposeViewControllerResult result) {
    switch(result) {
        //  This means the user cancelled without sending the Tweet
        case SLComposeViewControllerResultCancelled:
            break;
        //  This means the user hit 'Send'
        case SLComposeViewControllerResultDone:
            break;
    }

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:^{
            NSLog(@"Tweet Sheet has been dismissed.");
        }];
    });
};
```

> Source: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/ios/using-tweet-sheet

Answer (score 2):

```
-(void)shareViewTwitter:(NSString*)str
{
    TWTweetComposeViewController *twitter = [[TWTweetComposeViewController alloc] init];

    // Optional: set an image, url and initial text

    [twitter setInitialText:@"Some Text"];

    // Show the controller
    [self presentModalViewController:twitter animated:YES];

    // Called when the tweet dialog has been closed (Here your Action will be triggered)
    twitter.completionHandler = ^(TWTweetComposeViewControllerResult result)
    {
        NSString *title = @"Tweet Status";
        NSString *msg;

        if (result == TWTweetComposeViewControllerResultCancelled)
// Your Action

            msg = @"Tweet compostion was canceled.";
        else msg = @"Tweet composition completed."; // Your Action

        // Show alert to see how things went...
        UIAlertView* alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:title message:msg delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Okay" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alertView show];

        // Dismiss the controller

        [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

    };

}
```